# ROS2 on Windows 10 - `colcon build` uses wrong Python version: "No module named *"

Tags: ros2, python, colcon

When building my workspace with `colcon build`, it fails because of missing Python packages:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'em'

'em' is just an example, different project give different errors. When trying to fix this, I see the packages *are* already installed:

```
> python -m pip install empy
Requirement already satisfied: empy in c:\dev\ros2_humble\.venv\lib\site-packages (3.3.4)
```

After a little investigation I read the following in the logs:

> --- stderr: geographic_msgs
> CMake Error at C:/dev/ros2_humble/share/rosidl_adapter/cmake/rosidl_adapt_interfaces.cmake:59 (message):
> execute_process(C:/Program Files/Python310/python.exe -m rosidl_adapter

`colcon` is using the wrong version of Python... But I am running all the above after sourcing ROS2, from inside the ROS2 virtual environment.

How can I get `colcon` to stick with the right Python version?

Comment: Also see this `colcon` issue: https://github.com/colcon/colcon-core/issues/598

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems CMake is at fault here, even without `colcon` it just refuses to use the activated Python 3.8 venv, and instead falling back on the highest available Python version.

You can work around with by adding a CMake flag:

```
colcon build --cmake-args -DPython3_FIND_VIRTUALENV="ONLY"
```

Note that the "3" in "Python3_" is important here.

---

A permanent solution can be modifying the CMake scripts in the ROS install.

In `[ros_install]/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/python.cmake`, modify this line:

```
  find_package(Python3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter)
```

To look like:

```
  find_package(Python3 3.8 EXACT REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter)
```

This does not enforce virtual environment specifically, but it does lock into Python 3.8 specifically.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was only fixed after I edited the file: [ros_install]/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/python.cmake
Thanks to Roberto
My arguments were ignored when i used the command:
colcon build --cmake-args -DPython3_FIND_VIRTUALENV="ONLY"